# Properly Designing a Multiprocessing.Manager Custom Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, multiprocessing

I want to use the multiprocessing.Manager() object so I can asynchronously send information from a worker to the manager to send information to a server.  What I have is roughly 10 instances writing PDFs to disk.  I then wanted to use the manager object in the multiprocessing package to send that data to my S3 bucket because I do not want to hold up the local content generation.

So I was wondering if I create a custom manager object, is this the proper way to do this? Will each process submitted to the manager object get queued? or if I call multiple uploads, will the manager drop some of the calls?

Below is a sample code of what I am thinking of doing:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class UploadClass(object):
    def upload(self, filePath, params, destUrl):
        # do stuff
        return results

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('uploads', UploadClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    upload = manager.uploads()
    # do this wait for completion or do they perform this async
    print upload.upload(r"< path >", {...}, "some url")
    print upload.upload(r"< path >", {...}, "some url")
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to have ten different processes (are these unique instances of the same python script, or just multiprocessing.Process instances spawned inside one script?), which all write PDFs to disk. Once they're done writing, each instance will send the path of the file to a single `multiprocessing.Manager`, which should upload the files one at a time (meaning no parallel uploads). Is that right?

Comment: Also, do you care about getting a result back from the upload process? Or do you just want to fire off the upload in the background and forget about it?

Comment: @dano - it would be helpful to get back a message of some sort from the process to ensure the process worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer some of your questions:

> Will each process submitted to the manager object get queued?

The `Manager` server spawns a new thread to handle each incoming request, so all your requests will starting being handled instantly. You can see this inside of `multiprocessing/managers.py`:

```
def serve_forever(self):
    '''
    Run the server forever
    '''
    current_process()._manager_server = self
    try:
        try:
            while 1:
                try:
                    c = self.listener.accept()
                except (OSError, IOError):
                    continue
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_request, args=(c,))
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            pass
    finally:
        self.stop = 999
        self.listener.close()
```

> if I call multiple uploads, will the manager drop some of the calls?

No, none of the calls will be dropped.

> ```
> # do this wait for completion or do they perform this async
> print upload.upload(r"< path >", {...}, "some url")
> print upload.upload(r"< path >", {...}, "some url")
> ```

Both of the calls to `upload.upload` will be synchronous; they won't return until `UploadClass.upload` has completed. However, if you were to have multiple scripts/threads/processes calling `upload.upload` concurrently, each unique call would be happening concurrently inside its own thread in the `Manager` server process.

And your most most important question:

> is this the proper way to do this?

I would say no, if I understand the question properly. If you just have one script, and then spawn ten `multiprocessing.Process` instances inside that one script to write out the PDFs, then you should just use another `multiprocessing.Process` to handle the uploads:

```
def upload(self, q):
    for payload in iter(q.get, None):  # Keep getting from the queue until a None is found
        filePath, params, destUrl = payload
        # do stuff

def write_pdf(pdf_file_info, q):
   # write a pdf to disk here
   q.put((filepath, params, destUrl))  # Send work to the uploader
   # Move on with whatever comes next.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Start uploader
    upload_proc = multiprocessing.Process(upload, args=(pdf_queue,))
    upload_proc.start()

    # Start pdf writers
    procs = []
    for pdf in pdfs_to_write: 
         p = multiprocessing.Process(write_pdf, args=(pdf, pdf_queue))
         p.start()
         p.append(procs)

    # Wait for pdf writers and uploader to finish.
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
    pdf_queue.put(None) # Sending None breaks the for loop inside upload
    upload_proc.join()
```

If you're actually ok with concurrent uploads, then there's no need to have a separate `upload` process at all - just upload from the pdf writing processes directly.

It's hard to tell from your question if this is exactly what you're doing, though. Once you clarify, I'll adjust this last piece to fit your specific use-case.

Comment: Why spawn processes to put data into the queue instead of directly putting from the main process?

Comment: @Sir_FZ The OP stated that he had multiple instances writing PDFs: *"What I have is roughly 10 instances writing PDFs to disk"*. So there are multiple workers that end up putting items into the queue in parallel.

Comment: Good point. But when using the Manager, the OP has the advantage of processing multiple uploads concurrently (since the Manager forks a thread for each request) and since it involves IO, concurrency applies. While in your solution, you have a single process handling the uploads sequentially. I suggest using a ThreadPool in the upload process for asynchronously handling the upload requests put into the queue.

Comment: @Sir_FZ I got the impression the OP doesn't want the uploads to run concurrently. I can't figure out why else he would want to use a `Manager` instead of just spawning a thread or something like that. If concurrent uploads really are ok, then running a thread pool in the upload process would definitely make sense. You could even have a thread pool for each worker process to avoid the IPC overhead of passing data to a separate upload process, though that would make it harder to optimize the number of upload threads running.

Comment: Totally agree. I guess he prefers the upload to be done asynchronously based on his example and the question on whether the requests will run sequentially or asynchronously. This should probably be clearer in the question.

Comment: Correct, I would like the uploader to occur async because I want to be able to still generate content while the files move to the S3